# secured password with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, passwords, character

I am very new to regular expression, I did a research and got a little understanding
what I need is a password that matches those specifications

1. any alphabetic character (at least one)
2. any numeric character (at least one)
3. no spaces
4. special characters (0 or more)

what I got to is this

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?!\S)$
```

which matches 1, 2, 3 specifications but not 4 
I tried different stuff on 4, but I failed

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very close. This seems to solve your problem:

```
preg_match("/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(\S+)$/i", $password)
```

I made two changes.

1. Just a little shortening by using the `i` modifier (match case-insensitive). This allows to remove the A-Z`.
2. The `(?!\S)` does not really help here, I think. Instead you can simply make your actual match only consist of non-space characters (the `\S+`). This will also immediately allow special characters in your password (really anything rexcept for spaces).

If you only want to allow a certain set of special characters, replace the `\S` by a character class containing letters, digits and all characters you want to allow. By the way, if you want to make sure your password has a certain minimum length, you could change that `+` into `{8,}` for example.

Comment: perfect work, thank you, I would like to +100 :) you but it needs 15 reputation and I have only 8, thank you again :)

Comment: Or faster still... `/^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(\S+)$/i`

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for a weird regular expression. Especially since you want to make sure that the password **contains** or **does not contain**, and it doesn't matter where it appears:

```
<?php

/**
 * Validates the password:
 *  * Has at least one alphabet character
 *  * Has at least one digit
 *  * Has no spaces
 *
 * @param string $password  Password to validate
 *
 * @return bool             Whether $password is valid or not.
 */
function validate_password($password) {
    //If no alphabet characters found, return false.
    if (!preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $password)) {
        return false;
    }
    //If no digits found, return false.
    if (!preg_match("/[0-9]/", $password)) {
        return false;
    }
    //If a space is found, return false.
    if (strpos($password, " ") !== false) {
        return false;
    }
    //Special characters are optional, so no checking.
    //If nothing happened so far, the password is valid. Return true.
    return true;
}

var_dump(
    validate_password("test"),          //False, no digits
    validate_password("test123 test"),  //False, space
    validate_password("123456"),        //False, no alphabet
    validate_password("test1234")       //True
);
```

Comment: +1 You could also create a "threshold" to ensure that at least 3 of 4 have been satisfied or something...  i.e. instead of returning for any one failure, keep a count of how many conditions are met.  Then return that the count was above the necessary threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Use three separate regexes - one to check that there is an alphabetic character, one to check that there is a digit, and one to check that there are no spaces. While it is possible to do this all with a single regex, each additional condition increases the complexity of the regex significantly.

```
preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $passwd) && preg_match("/[0-9]/", $passwd) && !preg_match("/ /", $passwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be something like this:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=\S*$)(?=[0-9a-zA-Z.,;~!@#$%^&*()\-+=\\\]+$)
```

Add all the special characters you need.

**Edit**: replying to some comments, here is the result of a test run:

```
<?php

$re = '/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=\S*$)(?=[0-9a-zA-Z.,;~!@#$%^&*()\-+=\\\]+$)/';

$s = 'A2x.';

echo preg_match($re, $s);

?>
```

Tested with CLI under Ubuntu:

```
me@mymachine$ php _.php
1
```

And it gets `0` or `1` depending on the value of `$s` ;)

Comment: That regex can never be matched, as it contains two end-of-line characters (`$`).

Comment: And m.buettner's solution is perfect. Upvoting.

Comment: @duskwuff: You can have as many anchors as you want, as long as each one is in its own lookahead.  However, the `(?=\S*$)` part makes no sense.  The fourth lookahead enumerates all of the allowed characters, none of which are whitespace characters.  There's no need for a separate lookahead to ensure that all the characters are non-whitespace.